# REST service by Flasks servers different images from different paths for each url request?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am trying to implement very basic REST service on Flask. I hve differnt images in my computer located at different file paths and I like to show them to client for each different url address. For instance;

```
www.bla.com/get_image_A # returns image_A.png from path/to/file1
www.bla.com/get_image_B # returns image_B.png from path2/to/file2
```

Antoher concern is to hide full path from the client so if the image at completely another location then the flask root then I dont want to show my full path to file against possible hacker guys.

Is it possible to implement it in Flask?

I tried to do like this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['IMAGES_1_STATIC_PATH'] = '/Common/path/to/some/images'

@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def ml_reports_path(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['IMAGES_1_STATIC_PATH'] , filename)

@app.route('/get_some_images')
def tff_predictions():
    return render_template('get_some_images.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=4999, host='0.0.0.0')
```

get_seom_images.html

```
<img src="{{ url_for('ml_reports_path', filename = 'image1.png') }}">
```

This does not work and the file path is show /image1.png at browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are you getting an error? If so, please share the error and the full stacktrace.

Comment: does not work -> instead of /Common/path/to/some/images/image1.png browser tries to open /image1.png

Comment: The browser *should* try to open `/image1.png`. That's what you're telling it to access when you use `url_for('ml_reports_path', filename='image1.png')`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `@app.route('/Common/path/to/some/images/<path:filename>')`?

Comment: this is what I got when I load the page <img src="/image1.png"> and doesn't it need to be /Common/path/to/some/images/image1.png